# Finding $\int \frac{1+\sin x \cos x}{1-5\sin^2 x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Find $\int \frac{1+\sin x \cos x}{1-5\sin^2 x}dx$

I used a bit of trig identities to get: $\int \frac {2+\sin (2x)}{-4+\cos(2x)}dx$ and using the substitution: $t= \tan (2x)$ I got to a long partial fractions calculation which doesn't seem right.

Any hints on how to do it please?

Comment: The second formula does not seems to be correct. But the idea would be the tangent half-angle substitution $t=\tan(x)$. Then partial fraction decomposition would lead to the result.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici don't we use $\tan x$ (instead of $\frac x 2$) only when all the powers of sin and cos are even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator of your second integral should be $-3+5\cos 2x$, because
from the identities $\sin x\cos x=\frac{\sin 2x}{2}$ and $\sin ^{2}x=\frac{
1-\cos 2x}{2}$ we obtain

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1+\sin x\cos x}{1-5\sin ^{2}x}=\frac{2+\sin 2x}{-3+5\cos 2x}.
\end{equation*}

To evaluate

\begin{equation*}
\int \frac{2+\sin 2x}{-3+5\cos 2x}dx
\end{equation*}

we can use the standard half-angle substitution $t=\tan x$. Since $dt=\left(
t^{2}+1\right) dx$, $\sin 2x=\frac{2t}{t^{2}+1}$ and $\cos 2x=\frac{1-t^{2}}{
t^{2}+1}$, we thus have

\begin{eqnarray*}\int \frac{2+\sin 2x}{-3+5\cos 2x}dx
=\int \frac{t^{2}+t+1}{-\left( 2t-1\right) \left( 2t+1\right) \left(
t^{2}+1\right) }dt
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, using partial fractions decomposition, we obtain

\begin{equation*}
\frac{t^{2}+t+1}{-\left( 2t-1\right) \left( 2t+1\right) \left(
t^{2}+1\right) }=-\frac{7/20}{t-1/2}+\frac{3/20}{t+1/2}+\frac{t/5}{t^{2}+1}.
\end{equation*}

As such,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{2+\sin 2x}{-3+5\cos 2x}dx
&=&-\frac{7}{20}\ln \left| \tan x-\frac{1}{2}\right| +\frac{3}{20}\ln \left|
\tan x+\frac{1}{2}\right| \\&&+\frac{1}{10}\ln \left| \tan ^{2}x+1\right| +C.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$\int\frac{1+\sin x\cos x}{1-5\sin^2x}\mathrm{d}x
=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-5\sin^2x}+\int\frac{\sin x\cos x}{1-5\sin^2x}\mathrm{d}x$$
and
$$\int\frac{\sin x\cos x}{1-5\sin^2x}\mathrm{d}x
=-\frac{1}{10}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(1-5\sin^2x\right)}{1-5\sin^2x}
=-\frac{1}{10}\ln\left(1-5\sin^2x\right).$$
Then,
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-5\sin^2x}
=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\cos^2x-4\sin^2x}
=\int\frac{1}{1-4\tan^2x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\cos^2x}
=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(2\tan x\right)}{1-\left(2\tan x\right)^2}
=\frac{1}{2}\tanh^{-1}\left(2\tan x\right).$$

Comment: What does the $d(...)$ mean? is it $dx$?

Comment: It is the differentiation operation : for example, $\mathrm{d}\left(1-5\sin^2x\right)=-10\sin x\cos x\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: The final result in the form $\frac12\ln\Bigl(\dfrac{1+2\tan x}{1-2\tan x}\Bigr)$ may be more expressive.

Comment: I did not try to simplify it, but your formula is indeed very nice, well done!

Comment: We could have expanded the denominator for third line to: $(1+\sqrt5\sin x)(1-\sqrt 5 \sin x)$ and then continue with partial fractions right?

Comment: It is possible (it is what I tried at first), but $\frac{1}{1\pm\sqrt{5}\sin x}$ seems to be a bit more difficult to integrate than the factorized expression.

Comment: Is there a way to solve the last equality without using hyperbolic functions?

Comment: You can see the last result as the log formula (see Bernard's comment). You can also write the integral's value with the logarithm. I do not know if this helps you...

Comment: It's just the numerator isn't exactly the derivative of the denominator (because of the power of 2) so I don't see how to use the log formula...

Comment: No, I meant $$\tanh^{-1}\left(y\right)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)$$ for all $|y|<1$. It is a general formula.